# What is the fastest way to extract all n-grams of lengths 1, 2, and 3 from a body of text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, text-processing, n-gram

I have many bodies of text, and for each of them, I want to extract all unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams (words, not characters) and insert the counts and ngram lengths into another table.

Right now I am thinking of unnesting a regexp-splitted body of text using WITH ORDINALITY, and then using multiple subqueries for the bigrams and trigrams, but that requires ordering . However, I think this might be an inefficient way of going about it, since this sort of positional data should normally be accessed by index.

I am currently implementing this in Python, and a huge bottleneck is the dictionary insertion and searching of dictionaries/sets for stopwords.

Here is a very basic example:

Input:

`This is a small, small sentence.`

Output

```
ngram                | count | length
-------------------------------------
this                 | 1 | 1
is                   | 1 | 1
a                    | 1 | 1
small                | 2 | 1
sentence             | 1 | 1
this is              | 1 | 2 
is a                 | 1 | 2
a small              | 1 | 2
small small          | 1 | 2
small sentence       | 1 | 2
this is a            | 1 | 3
is a small           | 1 | 3
a small small        | 1 | 3
small small sentence | 1 | 3
```

Stripping the punctuation/handling lowercase is not an issue here, but getting the proper counts is important.

As an preliminary or intermediate step, I would also be removing stopwords which, in this case, are `this`, `a`, and `is`.

```
ngram                | count | length
--------------------------------------
small                | 2 | 1
sentence             | 1 | 1
small small          | 1 | 2
small sentence       | 1 | 2
small small sentence | 1 | 3
```

In the above example

Comment: Could you share a small sample of your table/field and your desired outputs of unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams. I think it would help us understand exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

Use the window function `lead()` to generate bigrams and trigrams, and unions to place all ngrams in a single list. In fact the most difficult was to keep the order in the resultset as in the starting sentence.

```
with my_table(sentence) as (
    values ('This is a small, small sentence.')
    ),

words as (
    select id, word
    from my_table,
    regexp_split_to_table(lower(sentence), '[^a-zA-Z]+') with ordinality as t(word, id)
    where word <> ''
    )

select ngram, count(*), length
from (
    select distinct on(id, ngram) id, ngram, length
    from (
        select id, word as ngram, 1 as length
        from words
        union all   
        select id, concat_ws(' ', word, lead(word, 1) over w), 2
        from words
        window w as (order by id)
        union all
        select id, concat_ws(' ', word, lead(word, 1) over w, lead(word, 2) over w), 3
        from words
        window w as (order by id)
        ) s
    order by id, ngram, length
    ) s
group by ngram, length
order by length, min(id);

        ngram         | count | length 
----------------------+-------+--------
 this                 |     1 |      1
 is                   |     1 |      1
 a                    |     1 |      1
 small                |     2 |      1
 sentence             |     1 |      1
 this is              |     1 |      2
 is a                 |     1 |      2
 a small              |     1 |      2
 small small          |     1 |      2
 small sentence       |     1 |      2
 this is a            |     1 |      3
 is a small           |     1 |      3
 a small small        |     1 |      3
 small small sentence |     1 |      3
(14 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive words as (  
  select id, translate(word, '.,', '') as word
  from my_table,
       regexp_split_to_table(lower(sentence), '\s+') with ordinality as t(word, id)
  where word <> ''
), ngrams (id, ngram) as (
  select id, array[word]
  from words
  where word not in ('this', 'a', 'is') -- remove stop words
  union all
  select c.id, p.ngram||c.word
  from words c
    join ngrams p on p.id + 1 = c.id 
     and cardinality(p.ngram) <= 2 -- limit to 3 words
)
select array_to_string(ngram, ' '), 
       count(*) over (partition by ngram) as "count", 
       cardinality(ngram) as length
from ngrams
order by cardinality(ngram);
```

For the sample `'This is a small, small sentence.'` this returns:

```
ngram                | count | length
---------------------+-------+-------
a                    |     1 |      1
is                   |     1 |      1
sentence             |     1 |      1
small                |     2 |      1
small                |     2 |      1
this                 |     1 |      1
this is              |     1 |      2
small small          |     1 |      2
is a                 |     1 |      2
small sentence       |     1 |      2
a small              |     1 |      2
is a small           |     1 |      3
this is a            |     1 |      3
a small small        |     1 |      3
small small sentence |     1 |      3
```

And with stop words removed:

```
ngram                | count | length
---------------------+-------+-------
sentence             |     1 |      1
small                |     2 |      1
small                |     2 |      1
small sentence       |     1 |      2
small small          |     1 |      2
small small sentence |     1 |      3
```

Not sure how fast this is going to be though.

Online example: http://rextester.com/CPPU86582